# How to print out specific items from a txt file?

Tags: php

I am attempting to print out the contents of a txt file. I have every item printing correctly within a table, although there are some small modifications I would like to make, yet I do not know how to.

This is how my activity.txt file looks

```
1,Cycle,3,Wednesday 8am
2,Aqua,7,Thursday 10am
3,Circuit,20,Monday 1pm
4,Zumba,15,Tuesday 5pm
```

I would like to not print out the unique ID that is at the start of the file. Instead, I would like to save them all as separate variables to use. Such as

```
$1
$2
$3
$4
```

I would also like to add usernames to the end of each activity, and then save those usernames into an array, like the following (usernames should not be printed on the page):

```
1,Cycle,3,Wednesday 8am: userY,userX,joe
2,Aqua,7,Thursday 10am: jack,john,joe
3,Circuit,20,Monday 1pm: oneUser,twoUser
4,Zumba,15,Tuesday 5pm: testUser,user
```

Which would then have arrays such as:

```
array1(userY,userX,joe);
array2(jack,john,joe);
array3(oneUser,twoUser);
array4(textUser,user);
```

The code I currently have that is printing my activities.txt file to the page is followed:

```
function bookActivity()
{
    $fileContentsArray = file ("activity.txt");
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($fileContentsArray as $one_persons_data)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        $splitted = preg_split('/,/', $one_persons_data);
        foreach ($splitted as $one) 
        {
            echo "<td>$one</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

}

All help and advice would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're essentially using a CSV file. Have you looked into PHP's built-in CSV functions, like `fgetcsv()` for parsing a CSV file?

Comment: I could quite possibly transfer to a CSV file. Although, my entire project has been built around .txt files

Comment: what happened to your other question>

Comment: Is there a reason you're not storing the data in a database?

Comment: My code is currently printing my txt file perfectly. I just need to attempt to try and make the changes that it needs.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - Sorry, forgot to mention that it is a project from a free online course that I am attempting to follow.

Comment: Is the ID at the beginning of each line the name of the variable? if so, what does it contain, the rest of the data?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - Yes, the ID, being the number, should be the name of the variable. It does not contain anything, I require it to be a variable so that I can use the variable to link back to the correct activity later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'oneUser';
$activities = array();
$activityKeys = array('ID','name','spaces','date');
function getActivities()
{
    global $activities,$activityKeys;
    $activities = array();
    $contents = file('activity.txt');
    foreach($contents as $line)
    {
        $activity = explode(':',$line);
        $data = array_combine($activityKeys,explode(',',$activity[0]));
        $users = isset($activity[1]) ? array_filter(explode(',',trim($activity[1]))) : array();
        $activities[$data['ID']] = compact('data','users');
    }
}
getActivities();
function userInActivity($activityID)
{
    global $activities;
    return in_array($_SESSION['userName'],$activities[$activityID]['users']);
}
function saveActivities()
{
    global $activities;
    $lines = array();
    foreach($activities as $id => $activity)
    {
        $lines[$id] = implode(',',$activity['data']).':'.implode(',',array_filter($activity['users']));
    }
    return file_put_contents('activity.txt',implode("\r\n",$lines)) !== false;
}
function bookActivity()
{
    global $activities;
    if(isset($_POST['book']))
    {
        $unbook = false;
        $bookID = intval($_POST['book']);
        if($bookID < 0)
        {
            //If a negative ID has been submitted, that means we are "unbooking"
            $unbook = true;
            $bookID = abs($bookID); //Set the ID back to the normal, positive value
        }
        if($unbook)
        {
            $users = $activities[$bookID]['users'];
            $userKey = array_search($_SESSION['userName'],$users);
            array_splice($activities[$bookID]['users'],$userKey,1);
        }
        else
        {
            $activities[$bookID]['users'][] = $_SESSION['userName'];
        }
        saveActivities();
    }
}
bookActivity();
function activityList($form=true)
{
    global $activities;
    if($form === true) echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php
                $firstKey = @array_shift(array_keys($activities));
                foreach(array_keys($activities[$firstKey]['data']) as $index => $column)
                {
                    echo '<th>'.$column.'</th>';
                }
                ?>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($activities as $activity)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                $id = $activity['data']['ID'];
                $activity['data']['spaces'] = $activity['data']['spaces']-count($activity['users']);
                foreach($activity['data'] as $item)
                {
                    echo '<td>'.$item.'</td>';
                }
                $booked = userInActivity($id,$_SESSION['userName']);
                $buttonText = $booked ? 'Unbook' : 'Book';
                $val = $booked ? -$id : $id;
                echo '<td><button type="submit" name="book" value="'.$val.'">'.$buttonText.'</button></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    if($form === true) echo '</form>';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Activities</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        activityList();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, now thats amazing. Thanks Smokey!
Although, since I'm extremely new to PHP, I am a little confused on how it is operating.
Where abouts are the IDs being saved? And how would I call them?

Also, regarding the usernames that is mentioned in my original question, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: PS. The ID does not HAVE to be the variable name. The variable name could possibly be the name of the activity, like 'Zumba'

Comment: @JadeMulholland See updated answer - the IDs are being made as the keys of each elements in the `$activities` array. Currently the value is NULL, as I'm still unsure what it should contain? Will it just be the array of usernames you mentioned?

Comment: Ahh alright. It's just that when I do echo $activities[1]; - It prints nothing.

Comment: @JadeMulholland Yes I know, as I said in my previous comment, the value is currently NULL which doesn't echo. What should the contents be?

Comment: Oh, sorry that's my fault. Read it completely wrong. Since PHP variables cannot start with a number, I think it would be best to have the unique IDs starting with 'a' such as 'a1', 'a2'. The activities.txt file can be changed to match that.

Comment: @JadeMulholland What's wrong with having them in an array? Is there a reason for them having to be separate variables? It's best not to change the contents just to change how the PHP will work.

Comment: So what must I now change within the function for the array to save the new IDs within the array?

Comment: @JadeMulholland Nothing, that's what it's already doing. As it says in my first comment on this answer, "the IDs are being made as the keys of each element". So the `$activities` array has elements of `ID => NULL` - but what should NULL be?

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain it a little better. I require the IDs to be saved as variables so that I can call on them later. There will be a separate "Book" button for each activity. Once this book button is pressed, I will then need to call on the related variable to add the logged in username to the end of the related activity list, like the example within my original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34433/discussion-between-smokeyphp-and-jade-mulholland)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you,

```
$i=1;
    foreach ($splitted as $one) 
    {
        if($i==1)
        {
            $i=0;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>$one</td>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is that doing differently from the code that I have?

Comment: It's starting at index 1, therefore skipping printing the first item

Comment: Oh, sorry! Completely missed that haha.
Now just need to attempt to save the index 0 as their own variables.

Comment: @JadeMulholland That can't be done the way you mentioned - see my answer

Comment: @mohan Your answer was better before - this one does the opposite of what needs to be done.